# Elegant map implementation

Tags: list, scala, collections, dictionary, set

having a list of ordered string to be compared to another list, I decided to implement one as a map in with the key is the first char of the string and the value the list of strings with the same first char.
In short I have something as this:

```
var list1:Map[Char, List[String]] = Map('a' -> List("alone", "away"))
var list2:List[String] = List("I", "am", "alone", "at", "home", "watching", "batman", "XD")
```

Now, having implemented my code this way, it is "hard" to work with them trying to consider the first one as a simple list, so I was wondering if there was another more elegant way to solve this problem.
If I have to verify if list1 has "alone", I have to first get the key 'a' and then call the method contains. I had to implement a thing like this.

```
if ( list1( "alone".charAt(0) ).contains( "alone" ) ) ...
```

It is ugly to have to extract each time the key and then compare the lists and I'd like to create a new map (or list) that implement this under the hood (it automatically extract the key and then work on the list).
What do you suggest?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I rewrote part of the question clarifying some points.
First list is ordered, the second one no.

Comment: do you have a list of ordered string? Or a ordered list of String? And why do you have this weired Map? Why not use a simple List?

Comment: Well, I have a list of ordered string, and I implemented my code this way believing it could be faster to do search and replace and some other things. I mean, it is faster to search in a smaller list that in all list, no?

Comment: You're probably best off using `Vector`.  It's fairly efficient with operations like that.

Comment: What are the advantages of Vector? There is no description on scala-lang documentation.

Comment: I am not familiar with scala, but could you not just use sets and their operations ? - Anyway.. In this case with sorted Lists, why not iterate over one list, comparing each element with the one at the same position in the other list ? O(n)

Comment: Because the lists have different sizes and don't have the same elements in the same positions. The first list is ordered, the second one no. The first has unique strings, the second no.

Comment: Vector's performance characteristics are described at http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From all I have seen you really want just a list. So use a List. (Or possibly a SortedSet http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedSet.html)

You seem to be concerned about performance but you neither state what part of which algorithm is to slow, nor how much faster it needs to go, nor do you provide plausible arguments that the approach you choose does meet these performance requirements. So again: just use List. Then measure performance. If it really is to slow, create a benchmark from it post code and results here and state how fast it needs to go.

Then people will be able to help.

Comment: I agree, I did not notice that there was also a HashSet... You know, when you came from a scripting language (autoit) you can't expect to know everything. Thanks for suggestion. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why using maps will help you compare lists of strings, but anyway:

If you don't mind using a mutable collection, and you are sure you have no repeats in your list (so you can actually use a set), then you can use the `MultiMap` trait:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
val mm = new HashMap[Char,Set[String]] with MultiMap[Char,String]
Seq("alone","away").foreach(s => mm.addBinding(s(0),s))

scala> mm
res2: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Char,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]]
 with scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Char,String] = 
 Map(a -> Set(alone, away))

scala> mm.entryExists('a',"alone")
```

Unfortunately, the multimappedness goes away when you use a collections operation (it's just a plain map from `Char` to `Set[String]` then).

Comment: I wanted to solve the ('a',"alone") part... I want to do something as mm.contains("alone") and it automatically do a thing as mm( "alone".charAt(0) ).contains( "alone" )...

Comment: @DDB - If you never actually need the `'a'` itself, I think this is a clear indication that you are not taking the right approach to solve your problem.  Also, don't forget you can just `def has(m: Map[Char,List[String]], s: String) = if (s.length>0) m.get(s.charAt(0)).map(_ contains s).getOrElse(false) else false` and then use that instead of typing out the whole mess each time.

Comment: Maybe I could solve the problem using an implicit def... I didn't think of it this way...

Comment: @DDB - You could use implicit conversions if you want the syntax m has "apples" instead of has(m,"apples").  Otherwise, the latter is more efficient.